# $f_n(x)=1-nx $ if $x\in [0,\frac{1}{n}],=0$ if $x\in [\frac{1}{n},1]$ in $C[0,1]$ equipped with $d(f,g):=\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|dt$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am dealing with the sequence,

> > $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
> >          1-nx &\text{ if } x\in [0,\frac{1}{n}]\\
> >             0 &\text{ if } x\in [\frac{1}{n},1]
> > \end{cases},
> > $$ in $C[0,1]$ equipped with $d(f,g):=\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|dt$

I need to verify it is Cauchy sequence and also convergent or not?

I want to show it is uniformly convergent. When I am trying to find its pointwise limit I can not understand its nature close to $0$.As, $n\to \infty$, $x\to 0$ then where $nx$ is going?
If I try to show it cauchy from direct definition $d(f_m,f_n)=\int_0^1(n-m)xdx=(n-m)/2$ how it will go to $0$ as $n,m \to \infty$

Comment: This is not the usual metric on $C[0,1]$. Have you shown it is complete with this metric?

Comment: It's actually not complete.

Comment: upsss....ok then I have to verify its cauchyness and covergence also....

Comment: Your calculation of $d(f_n,f_m)$ is off.  $f_n=1-nx$ only for $x\in[0,\frac{1}{n}]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m > n$, then as $m,n \to \infty$,

$$d(f_n,f_m) = \int_0^{1/m}|m-n|x \,dx + \int_{1/m}^{1/n}|1 - nx| \, dx \\ \leqslant \frac{m}{2m^2} + \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}\right) \to 0$$

Comment: Very nice....So Cauchy. Now how it is convergent?

Comment: Directly -- $d(f_n,0) = \int_0^{1/n} |1 - nx - 0| \, dx = 1/2n \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\int_0^1|f_n-0|=\frac{1}{2n} \rightarrow 0$. Thus $f_n \rightarrow 0$. Convergent sequences are always Cauchy. Can you prove this?

Comment: Can you assure pt wise limit goes to 0?

Comment: @Aweygan Thanks for catching. I even used Wolfram and still got it wrong.

Comment: @Arbin What do you mean? $\int_0^1|f_n -0| = d(f_n, 0)$. You should know that $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Why u are calculating $d(f_n,0)?$

Comment: If $d(f_n, 0) \rightarrow 0$ $f_n \rightarrow 0$ by definition.